# How to fix @ts-expect-error ts-migrate(2571) on Typescript when convert js to ts

Tags: node.js, typescript

I begin to start with typescript and I was trying to convert my JS file to TS.

I have a class with the function below

APP.JS

```
async function get_stocks_saved_on_database(request: any, response: any) {

  let mongoDatabaseStockOperations = new MongoDatabaseStockOperations()
  let all_ocorrencies = await mongoDatabaseStockOperations.findAllOcorrencesOrderByValue(Constants.STOCKS_REPORT_COLLECTION)

  // @ts-expect-error ts-migrate(2571) FIXME: Object is of type 'unknown'.
  all_ocorrencies.forEach((element: any) => {
    response.write(element.stock_name + " | " + element.stock_value + " | " + element.percent_difference + " | " + element.day + "\n")    
  });
  response.end()
}

async findAllOcorrencesOrderByValue(my_investments_collection: any){
  console.log("start findAllOcorrences")
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do async job
    MongoDb.MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      var dbo = db?.db(database_name);
      var mysort:MongoDb.Sort = {  "day": -1, "percent_difference": -1 };
      dbo?.collection(my_investments_collection).find().sort(mysort).collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true}).toArray(function(err, result) {          
                
        if (err) reject(err);
        console.log(result);
        resolve(result)
        db?.close();
        
      });
    });
    
  });
  
}
```

I dont know how to identify which is the object type of "all_ocorrencies" in

```
let all_ocorrencies = await mongoDatabaseStockOperations.findAllOcorrencesOrderByValue(Constants.STOCKS_REPORT_COLLECTION)
```

The function findAllOcorrencesOrderByValue return a Promise with objects from a mongodb database, but I don't how which is the type of that object.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Error `2571` refers to the skipping of type-checking on type `unknown`. Doing a type check will affirm a specific type.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `unknown` type

Error `2571` refers to the skipping of type-checking on type `unknown`. Doing a type check will affirm a specific type.

```
let x: unknown;

x.toString(); // Expected output: Error: Object is of type 'unknown'.
x + 1; // Expected output: Error: Object is of type 'unknown'.
Array[x] // Expected output: Error: Type 'unknown' cannot be used as an index type.
```

To certify that x is a specific type, we can pass it into an if statement

```
if (typeof x === 'string') x.toString(); // Inline if
if (typeof x === 'number') { // Multiline if
    x += 2;
}
```

It is often encourage to make sure that intellisense or your code editor's/IDE's autocomplete predicts methods and more information corresponding to the type.

https://tsplay.dev/wenlXN

Notice how any variable with an `unknown` type, no autocomplete is filled, where as when manually type-checked, it has all the autocomplete to the related type.

## Implementation

Where as the specific object that has the type unknown, I'm not sure of which, but the code should look something like this:

```
if (typeof x !== 'object') return;
```

In the case of `all_ocorrencies`:

```
if (typeof all_ocorrencies !== 'array') return; // Or handle it yourself
all_ocorrencies.forEach((element: any) => {
    response.write(element.stock_name + " | " + element.stock_value + " | " + element.percent_difference + " | " + element.day + "\n")    
});
```

In the case of `element`:

```
all_ocorrencies.forEach((element: unknown) => {
    if (typeof element !== 'object') return; // Or handle it yourself
    response.write(element.stock_name + " | " + element.stock_value + " | " + element.percent_difference + " | " + element.day + "\n")    
});
```